# Executar tarefa apenas quando o CTRL e mouse estiverem pressionados

Tags: javascript

Preciso movimentar o  `<input type="range">` apenas quando o <kbd>CTRL</kbd> e o **clique do mouse esquerdo** estiverem pressionados. Consegui fazer isso com esse código:

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 17) {
    document.onmousedown = function() {
      document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mousemove', ouvinteBrilho, false);
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

O problema é que mesmo depois de soltar o <kbd>CTRL</kbd> ele continua movimentando caso eu continue segurando o clique do mouse. Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma e sem sucesso:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 17) {
    document.querySelector('body').removeEventListener('mousemove', ouvinteBrilho);
  }
})
```

Ou:

```
document.onmouseup = function() {
  document.querySelector('body').removeEventListener('mousemove', ouvinteBrilho);
  return false;
}
```

Edit: Quando faço apenas com o <kbd>CTRL</kbd> funciona perfeitamente:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 17) {
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mousemove', ouvinteBrilho, false);
  }
})

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 17) {
    document.querySelector('body').removeEventListener('mousemove', ouvinteBrilho);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é adicionar um evento no `document` para verificar quando o `ctrl` é pressionado e liberado. Nestes instantes você pode habilitar/desabilitar o `input`.

*Obs.: para testar o exemplo abaixo utilizando o botão `Executar` é necessário efetuar o foco no iframe gerado. Para isto, basta clicar em uma área em branco em baixo do input, por exemplo. Depois só será possível movimentar o input com o `ctrl` pressionado. Se você copiar este trecho para um arquivo `.html` e executar na sua máquina, ao abrir o arquivo no navegador a função já estará disponível. O problema aqui é o foco do window que inicialmente está nesta própria página e não no iframe.*

```js
const myInput = document.querySelector('#myInput');
myInput.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (!e.ctrlKey) {
    myInput.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    myInput.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (!e.ctrlKey) {
 myInput.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
 myInput.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="range" id="myInput" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer usando dois eventos: `keydown` e `keyup`.

O primeiro vai verificar se a tecla pressionada é o <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (cód. 17) e cancela o eventos que bloqueiam o input, e o segundo (que significa que a tecla foi liberada) irá chamar uma função que bloqueia o input. Coloquei uma classe `.range` para que eventualmente você possa usar em vários inputs ao mesmo tempo.

*Para o snippet abaixo funcionar, é preciso clicar antes em qualquer área dele:*

```js
$(document).on("keydown keyup", function(e){
   if(e.which == 17 && e.type == "keydown") $(".range").off("mousemove mousedown");
   if(e.which == 17 && e.type == "keyup") bloqueia();
});

function bloqueia(){
   $(".range").on("mousemove mousedown", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
   });
}

function ouvinteBrilho(){
   console.clear();
   console.log("brilho");
}

bloqueia(); // chama a função que bloqueia os inputs
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="range" type="range">
<br>
<input class="range" type="range">
```